# Slider and Date Picker is not showing JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, slider

I am creating a page where every time a user presses a button, a row will appear in a table with 4 columns. I am trying to add slider and date picker. it works when i add it in HTML, but doesnt work when I have it in a javascript and jquery function.

Here is function that happens when I press the add button.

```
$(function() {

            $("#date").datepicker()

        });


        $(function()
        {
            $("#amount").val(60);
            $("#slider1").slider({

                slide: function(event, ui)
                {
                    $("#amount").val(ui.value); 
                },
                orientation: "horizontal",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 60
            });
        });


function addLab()
{
    var labs = $('#lab tr').length;
    if (labs <= 10)
    {
        var newSlider =  $('<div>', { id: 'slider1' });
        var newLab = $('<tr><td><input type="text" onchange="sumAll()" id="earnedLab" title="Enter Your Score Out Of 25."/></td><td>' + "25" + '</td><td><input type="text" id="date" /></td><td><div id="slider1" style="width: 200px"/></td></tr>'); 
        $('#lab').append(newLab);
    }
    else alert("No more boxes allowed for labs");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i figured it out... I should have been using classes, not IDs. I switched it and it worked..